# What does `{,*/}` mean in paths of Gruntfile.js?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

In `Gruntfile.js`, I have got:

```
watch: {
    styles: {
      files: [
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.less'
      ],
      tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
    }
}
```

For the path, what does `{,*/}` mean indeed? How does it differ to using double asterisks `**/`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This pattern is widely used in yeoman templates: it means to look only one level deep inside folder hierarchy. It is used mostly for performance reasons since watching too many files simultaneously can be slow (or even impossible).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Yeoman specifically. Do you have a reference to the performance issues?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, though it appears that the concern was more about the total number of file watches, irrespective of the depth of the directories.

Comment: I guess so, but less depth => less files (generally). Anyway, I don't think this approach is any good, because it trades correctness for performance.

Comment: So, based on this, whats the difference between using {,*/} and /*/ as I tried the single * and it worked fine in my grunt concat script...

Comment: Can we use this pattern in grunt as well?

Answer (score 28):

These are **[globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)** for Grunt, supported by the **[node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)** and **[minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch)** libraries.

Basically:

- `*` matches any number of characters, **but not** `/`
- `**` matches any number of characters, **including** `/`, as long as it's the only thing in a path part
- `{}` allows for a **comma-separated list of "or" expressions**

So, `styles/{,*/}*.less` matches the following files:

- LESS files inside `styles` directory
- LESS files inside **direct sub-directories** of `styles` directory (but no deeper)

Comment: Thank you! Save 2 hours for me. ;)

Answer (score 11):

I believe you're using a [minimatch pattern](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) there.

The double asterisk is a glob that causes recursion into subdirectories.

The single asterisk only matches 0 or more characters in the current directory (it matches every character except the slash character).

For example, a/**/d will match a/b/c/d.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [globbing-patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) .

The other answers had already answer what does`{,*/}*` mean.

But the different between `**/` and `{,*/}*` is **folder depth**.

- `/styles/{,*/}*.less` has been divided into two situation

  1. `/styles/*.less`
  2. `/styles/*/*.less`

For example

`/styles/{,*/}*.less` will match `/styles/x.less` (situation 1)

`/styles/{,*/}*.less` will also match `/styles/test/x.less` (situation 2)

But `/styles/{,*/}*.less` can't match `/styles/test/test1/x.less`

But `/styles/**/*.less` can do that